# Is the function $f(x) = x^2$ injective if the domain is $(-\infty, 0)$ and co-domain is $(0,\infty)$?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I know that $f(x) = x^2$ is not injective if the domain is $(\infty, -\infty)$ with the proof:
$x^2 = y^2$

$\pm x = \pm y$

But with the domain $(-\infty, 0)$, can you use the graph to proof by using the negative side of the parabola? If not, how do you proof with $x^2 = y^2$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $x^2=y^2$, then $x=\pm y$.  But if $x,y\in(-\infty,0)$, that means $x=y$

Comment: Thank you, Tanner. I usually go to tutoring but since campus is closed, I found this awesome website. Isn't x an element of domain and y is element of codomain? Is it $-x = +y$?

Comment: In what I wrote, $x$ and $y$ are both in the domain.  Call them $x_1$ and $x_2$ if that's less confusing:  if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ then $x_1=\pm x_2$ and if also $x_1,x_2<0$ that means $x_1=x_2$; that proves the function is injective

Comment: Oh, sorry for misunderstanding. This is what I got: If x1, x2 < 0. It means -x1 and -x2 and I just divide -1 from both sides which gives as you said x1 = x2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if $k\in (0,\infty)$, i.e. the codomain then $f(x)=k$ is equivalent to $x^2=k$. Then $x^2=k$ has solutions $\pm \sqrt{k}$. In particular, the only preimage of the point $k$ in $(-\infty,0)$ is $-\sqrt{k}$. Hence, this map is injective (and also surjective).

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Thank you, Alekos. I would of never thought of this way to proof. I really need to reread the chapter on proofs.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $x_1<x_2<0$. If $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ you have $x_1^2=x_2^2$ and therefore $x_1^2-x_2^2=0$. This means that $(x_1+x_2)(x_1-x_2)=0$. But $x_1+x_2<0$ and $(x_1-x_2) \neq 0$ since $x_1 \neq x_2$. This proves that $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$.